# To prevent the Action Name coming in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is any way in mvc to prevent the Action Name coming in the url when calling a specific action 
and not affect this when calling others action.

Comment: add ChildAction in header..

Comment: Are you asking something like this:
Controller, MyController, with actions Action1() and Action2() and you want http://myapp/mycontroller to go to Action1 but http://myapp/mycontoller/action2 to go to Action2?